# Why downloading updates in android ask wifi connection rather than mobile data?

Tags: wi-fi

Why did downloading updates in android ask wifi connection rather than mobile data?

Answer (score 2):

The size of update package is generally large so it by default uses only wifi rather than mobile data so that no money is deducted in case the mobile data is exhausted or there is no data plan.

### In old devices

Go to setings --> About device --> software updates.
Here you disable the option download software updates via WiFi and enable , automatically download software updates or select manually update.

### In new devices

If you're using a new device after clicking on check for updates ,you'll get a alert or popup showing what's the latest update, in most of the cases you will find a checkbox ticked against download using WiFi only, just disable the check box. If this is not the case then on the screen where you download the updates there should be three dots in upper right corner, you will be sure to find the option to change data usage preference there.